# C# IEnumerable being reset in child method

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have the below method:

```
private static List<List<job>> SplitJobsByMonth(IEnumerable<job> inactiveJobs)
{
    List<List<job>> jobsByMonth = new List<List<job>>();

    DateTime cutOff = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-1).Date;
    cutOff = cutOff.AddDays(-cutOff.Day + 1);

    List<job> temp;
    while (inactiveJobs.Count() > 0)
    {
        temp = inactiveJobs.Where(j => j.completeddt >= cutOff).ToList();
        jobsByMonth.Add(temp);
        inactiveJobs = inactiveJobs.Where(a => !temp.Contains(a));
        cutOff = cutOff.AddMonths(-1);
    }

    return jobsByMonth;
}
```

It aims to split the jobs by month. 'job' is a class, not a struct. In the while loop, the passed in IEnumerable is reset with each iteration to remove the jobs that have been processed:

```
inactiveJobs = inactiveJobs.Where(a => !temp.Contains(a));
```

Typically this reduces the content of this collection by quite a lot. However, on the next iteration the line:

```
temp = inactiveJobs.Where(j => j.completeddt >= cutOff).ToList();
```

restores the inactiveJobs object to the state it was when it was passed into the method - so the collection is full again.
I have solved this problem by refactoring this method slightly, but I am curious as to why this issue occurs as I can't explain it. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: in line `inactiveJobs = inactiveJobs.Where(a => !temp.Contains(a));` adding ToList or ToArray fixes the issue?

Comment: I assume this is cuased by the deferred execution of linq. Thus when using `Where` you´re not actally *executing* the query, but just *define* it. Simply use `Where(...).ToList()` as in the line before.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - if you could show us a complete sample with expected outputs we can help you move to that solution.

Comment: Adding ToList() fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a group by?

```
    private static List<List<job>> SplitJobsByMonth(IEnumerable<job> inactiveJobs)
    {
        var jobsByMonth = (from job in inactiveJobs
                            group job by new DateTime(job.completeddt.Year, job.completeddt.Month, 1)
                            into g
                            select g.ToList()).ToList();
        return jobsByMonth;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of deferred execution of LINQ's `Where`.

When you do this

```
inactiveJobs = inactiveJobs.Where(a => !temp.Contains(a));
```

no evaluation is actually happening until you start iterating the `IEnumerable`. If you add `ToList` after `Where`, the iteration would happen right away, so the content of `interactiveJobs` would be reduced:

```
inactiveJobs = inactiveJobs.Where(a => !temp.Contains(a)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In **LINQ**, queries have two different behaviors of execution: **immediate** and **deferred**.

The query is actually executed when the query variable is iterated over, not when the query variable is created. This is called deferred execution.

You can also force a query to execute immediately, which is useful for caching query results.

In order to make this add `.ToList()` in the end of your line:

```
inactiveJobs = inactiveJobs.Where(a => !temp.Contains(a)).ToList();
```

This executes the created query immediately and writes result to your variable.

You can see more about [this example Here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/linq/750/deferred-vs-immediate-query-execution-linq).